# Maven install goal - JBoss - java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote:/ /localhost:9999. The connection timed out

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to run my java web application using maven, but i am getting the below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.1.1
Final:deploy (default-cli) on project SpringMVC: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY:
ould not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-children-names",
[ERROR] "child-type" => "deployment"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote:
/localhost:9999. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swi
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please re
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecution
xception
```

I configured jboss-as-maven-plugin like below

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <force>true</force>                
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin123</password>                
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>target/SpringMVC.war</fileName>
                </fileNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Below is the my standalone.xml configuration

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>   
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Can any one please help me to sort out this issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and had trouble finding the solution, this worked for me - strangely enough it did not require the user name or password.  It looks like the old plug-in doesnt work with JBoss EAP 7

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the management-native interface is not configured in the JBOSS / Wildfly configuration file (eg standalone.xml). Make sure that the configuration file shows:

```
<management-interfaces>
    <native-interface security-realm = "ManagementRealm">
        <socket-binding native = "management-native" />
    </ native-interface>
    <http-interface security-realm = "ManagementRealm">
        <http-upgrade enabled = "true" />
        <socket-binding http = "management-http" />
    </ http-interface>
</ management-interfaces>

When starting the server, a message like the following should be observed:
17: 46: 45,684 INFO [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYRMT0001: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
```